# Does ADO work with ODBC drivers or only OLE DB providers?

Tags: postgresql, vba, excel, ado

I am trying to create some VBA code to automate dashboard creation against a PostgreSQL database. I have heard the OLE DB driver is unreliable and it looks like it hasn't been touched in several years. Does ADO work with an ODBC driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply reference the DSN:

```
oConn.Open "DSN=mySystemDSN;" & _ 
           "Uid=myUsername;" & _ 
           "Pwd=myPassword"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was just reading a book (not a very good one, I guess) that strongly implied that this could not be done. Thank you.